# Primeng p-multiSelect search function is not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm working with PrimeNg to filter columns on my p-table.

I have `p-multiSelect` nested inside a `p-ColumnFilter`.

The filtering is working as expected, however the search function inside the `p-multiSelect` is always returning `no results found`.

Here is my template code:

```xml
<th class="table-header-primary" [ngStyle]="{'width':'200px'}" [pSortableColumn]="'docCategory'">Type
  <p-columnFilter  class="p-ml-auto" type="text" field="doctypeLabel"  matchMode="in" display="menu"  [showApplyButton]="false" [showMatchModes]="false" [showOperator]="false" [showAddButton]="false">
    <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
      <p-multiSelect  [(ngModel)]="doctypeLabel" [options]="_doctypeLabelList"  placeholder="Select" (onChange)="filter($event.value)">
      </p-multiSelect>
      </ng-template>
  </p-columnFilter></th>
```

Here is my relevant typescript file:

```js
_doctypeLabelList:any[]=[];
doctypeLabel:any="";
  constructor() {
  }
```

I've attached two photos that I hope make my issue clear.

My multiselect dropdown, populated with appropriate fields from `_doctypeLabelList`:

[image: 1]

Once I try to search for matching values in dropdown:

[image: 2]

I have tried to one way bind `doctypeLabel` but that did not work. The `_doctypeLabelList` is showing fine in the options dropdown, it's just when searching in the input bar always results in immediate `no results found`. I'm really at a lost of what else to try. I've looked at the PrimeNg documentation over and over and didn't find any results. The example in the documentation was a rather simple use case, so I'm wondering if somehow the `p-columnFilter` is affecting my `p-multiSelect`.

Comment: how _doctypeLabelList looks like?, have you tried with `filterBy` property, when filtering is enabled, filterBy decides which field or fields (comma separated) to search against.

Comment: Hi Denes, thanks for reaching out. _doctypeLabelList looks as it should, it has all the appropriate values which populate the option dropdown. I have used [filterBy] = "doctypeLabel" and it unfortunately did not work. I feel like I'm missing some simple piece, but for the life of me cannot figure out what it could be.

Comment: I mean, what structure has your _doctypeLabelList. Has a "label" property?. By the default, primeng options have the following structure. a "label" property, and a "value" property. If your options doesnt have that structure, you must specify it

Comment: Your right, I just discovered this. The options must be bound to SelectedItem array, but mine is just a normal string[ ]. It seems very cumbersome and expensive for me to change each array to fit the "label" and "value" property. Is there a way around this? If my _doctypeLabelList was : ["Mike", "Steve", "Mark", "Mickey"], how would this work?

Comment: They have an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10122) related to this, so until that issue is fixed, you have to change your options, you can do it with a map function

Comment: Right, I now see that. They should update the documentation until that is fixed. I was able to get it working after transferring my string array to {label: val, value: val}

Answer (score 8):

Had the same annoying problem, initially I used a **string[]** as input for options which gave me the same issue.

Fixed it by converting the string array to a **SelectItem[]** array and use that as [options] input.

```
public items: string[]; // <-- OLD INPUT 

// NEW INPUT: return items as SelectItem
get itemsAsSelectItems(): SelectItem [] {
  return this.items.map((item) => ({ label: item, value: item } as SelectItem));
}
```

Template implementation:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="itemsAsSelectItems" ... ></p-multiSelect>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the original poster already said they got it working, but when trying to find the answer myself, there was no good explanation given.  So I want to clear up what I did.

```
printersForFilter: any[] = [];
```

Original line:

```
<p-multiSelect [ngModel]="value" [options]="jobTypesForFilter" placeholder="Any" (onChange)="filter($event?.value)">
```

Working line:

```
<p-multiSelect [ngModel]="value" [options]="jobTypesForFilter" placeholder="Any" (onChange)="filter($event?.value)" [optionValue]="'value'" [optionLabel]="'id'">
```

Original line:

```
this.printersForFilter = Object.values([...new Set(sourceData.map((x) => x.printerDescription ?? ''))]);
```

Working line:

```
this.printersForFilter = Object.values([...new Set(sourceData.map((x) => x.printerDescription ?? ''))]).map(x => ({ id: x, value: x}));
```

PrimeNg seems unable to just use the same property as both a value and an id.

Came to my answer by reading this thread, and these two links:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10122
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9584

Seems to be common and their documentation does not indicate this as all.